# Proving that the equality of ordered pairs formula is true using logical equivalences

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, set-theory

First of all I want to apologize for any english mistake or a mistake about how to "behave" on this website, that's my first time posting a question here and english is not my first language so this text might have some translation problems.

**Context**

I'm going a computer science major and one of my subjects on this first year is Logic and Discrete Math. During class today our professor told us to do the following exercise:
Prove that (a , b) = (x, y) <=> a = x e b = y (or equality of ordered pairs) is true by using logic equivalences.
We are not obligated to do this exercise (since professor didn't asked us to deliver it to him) but I'm trying to do it since morning and I'm stuggling a lot to understand how to use logical equivalences on set theory, specially for ordered pairs.

**What I have so far**

I did tried to build a solution to it, here's what I've done so far:

1. x ϵ (a , b) ---------------------------- Premise
2. x ϵ a  or  x ϵ b ----------------------- Definition ; 1
3. not(not x ϵ a  or not x ϵ b) ----------- Double Negation ; 2
4. not(not x ϵ a)  and  not(not x ϵ b) ---- De Morgan's ; 3
5. x ϵ a  and  x ϵ b ---------------------- Double Negation ; 4
6. x ϵ a ---------------------------------- Simplification; 5

My theory is that once I do this I can confirm that a = x, then I just have to do the same thing to confirm b = y, but I don't really know if that's how you should do it, first because I'm not sure if I can use Double Negation like this and second because, like I said, I'm really struggling a lot to understand this logic part, specially for set theory and ordened pairs so I don't actually know if what I did in 2. is the definition of an ordened pair or not.

**Question**

My main question is: can someone please help me to solve this or tell if what I'm doing is right or not? I guess it's not that hard (giving that as far as I searched this seems to be basic logic) but it's being really hard for me to understand it and I've been searching for help the entire day (even found some pretty similar questions here but these weren't aiming for a logical equivalence answer, which is the really hard thing to me) and still got nothing.

How could I proof the equality of ordered pairs using logical equivalences?

Comment: A pretty common definition of ordered pairs that's used in the context of set theory is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski's_definition, where $(a,b)$ is represented by the set $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ (the statement "if $x\in(a,b)$ then $x\in a$ or $x\in b$" doesn't match this definition). We're considering "$(a,b)=(x,y)$ iff $a=b$ and $x=y$", substituting the definition in, we get that what we're trying to prove from a set-theoretical perspective is "$\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ iff $a=b$ and $x=y$".

Comment: I see... I was reading the wikipedia article right now, so the idea is to use {a} = {c} or {a} = {d} as the initial premisse on the proof?

Comment: The general idea is to use "{a}={x} and {a,b}={x,y}" since the premise is that the ordered pairs themselves are equal, although there are some small complications when a=b (i.e. {a}={a,b}) that can be resolved in the proof.

Comment: oh I see, I'll try to use both as premises then, I also tried to, following the wiki article, use other premises to get a = x and b = y
I used a = b, (a,b) = (x,y), a ∈ {a} and y ∈ {y} as premisses, I said that iff a = b then {{a}, {a,b}} = {{a}, {a, a} = {a} and since (x,y) = (a,b) then (x,y) = {a} which means that a = x = y = b. 
I also just tried to do the same but with a != b right now, using a = x as a last premisse, which would mean that b = y != a = x
is it right?

Comment: It looks like a good start for proving the "(a,b)=(x,y) → a=x and b=y" half of the problem, although I have a few suggestions:
*I think {{a}, {a,b}} = {{a}, {a, a} = {a} is an error, {{a},{a,b}}={{a}} when a=b.
*You don't really need a ∈ {a} and y ∈ {y} as premises, since {a} is defined to mean the set containing only a.
*In the a != b case, instead of assuming a=x as a premise, we can prove it: since {a,b} has cardinality 2, {{a},{a,b}} has exactly one member with cardinality 1, namely {a}. Since (x,y)=(a,b), (x,y) also has exactly one singleton member, so x != y. Then we continue

Comment: What remains is to show the other half of the biconditional, "a=x and b=y → (a,b)=(x,y)"

Comment: I think I got it! If that's enough to prove "(a,b)=(x,y) → a=x and b=y" then, I just need to work with it now and then try to prove "a=x and b=y → (a,b)=(x,y)" later. Just one more question if I may ask: how could I begin to prove the latter? I mean to prove it I'll have to (probably) turn "a=x and b=y" into 2 ordered pairs and then prove that they are equal, but how can I turn then into ordered pairs?

Comment: Sorry for the late response! One way to get started is the fact that from a=x, we get {a}={x} by extensionality. The rest should be pretty similar to this step

Comment: No worries! and sure! I think I finally got it, thank you so much for helping me!